# What is the query to find the salary of employees having more salary than his/her manager?

Tags: sql, database, plsql, ssms, aggregation

Suppose there is a below table

| EmpID | EmpName | ManagerID | EmpSalary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 2 | 1000 |
| 2 | DEF | 3 | 2000 |
| 10 | GHI | 11 | 5000 |
| 3 | JKL | 4 | 1000 |

Now we know that EmpID = 2 should be the output because it has higher salary than its manager.

But what query can we write to get this output? I am really confused here

Comment: PL/SQL and SSMS? Odd combination... Which dbms are you actually using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH CTE(EmpID,     EmpName,    ManagerID,  EmpSalary) AS
 (

    SELECT 1,   'ABC' , 2 , 1000 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 ,  'DEF' , 3 , 2000  UNION ALL
    SELECT 10 , 'GHI'   ,11 ,   5000  UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 ,  'JKL' , 4 , 1000
 )
 SELECT T.EmpID,T.EmpName,T.ManagerID,T.EmpSalary,T2.EmpSalary AS MANAGER_SALARY
 FROM CTE AS T
 JOIN CTE AS T2 ON T.ManagerID=T2.EmpID
 --WHERE T.EmpSalary>T2.EmpSalary
```

This is called "self-join". CTE in the above code represents your table's data.
Please take a look how table is joined with itself (I commented the WHERE-condition) to show employee's an manager'ssalaries

Comment: The *idea* itself is OK, but your implementation just won't work, at least not in an Oracle database. I suggest you fix it.